# Binding data to gridview. How to use paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

It is popping an exception saying I can not using paging on the server side.

```
conn.Open(); 
string querstring = "select * from gt_transaction_log where LogTimeStamp between '2013-09-19 07:06:00.077' and '2013-09-19 10:28:25.163' ";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querstring, conn);
GridView1.EmptyDataText = "no record found";
GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataBind();

GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
GridView1.PageSize = 5;
```

Comment: Try moving last two commands above the DataBind method.

Comment: Look this sample : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use paging with a `DataReader`. So problem is with this line:

`GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

You should fill GridView using a `Dataset` or a `Datatable` using a `DataAdapter`.

Example:

// Using **`DataTable`**

```
string querstring = "select * from gt_transaction_log where LogTimeStamp between
                     '2013-09-19 07:06:00.077' and '2013-09-19 10:28:25.163' ";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(querstring , conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource=dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

// Using **`DataSet`**

```
string querstring = "select * from gt_transaction_log where LogTimeStamp between
                     '2013-09-19 07:06:00.077' and '2013-09-19 10:28:25.163' ";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(querstring , conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "Table_Name"); // you can supply a table name
GridView1.DataSource=ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

You must specify if you want paging in the UI of the page, that is :

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="grid_PageIndexChanging" />
```

Then in the cs file:

```
 protected void grid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindGrid();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Where BindGrid() method is the one in which we bind the grid.

Answer (score 0):

on design view , click Gridview > allow paging
or use SQLdatasource instead, then allow paging

Answer (score -2):

You can try using this code.......

```
String constring = "Data Source=dsdsdsds;Initial Catalog=table;User Id=uid;Password=pass";
SqlConnection conqav = new SqlConnection(constring);
String takeffty = "select top 10 * from table";
conqav.Open();
SqlCommand comqav = new SqlCommand(takeffty,conqav);
GridView1.DataSource = comqav.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataBind();
conqav.Close();
```